# How do I backcolor in verbatim?

Tags: spacing, color, boxes, verbatim

I have some code I want to typeset as verbatim (lstlisting would be ok as well) - but I want to highlight some parts of it via a different background color, i.e. something like this:

```
\begin{verbatim}
hello \colorbox{red}{world} blah
hello world blub
\end{verbatim}
```

Where `colorbox` should not be interpreted verbatim and should not introduce additional horizontal spaces, i.e. blah and blub should be correctly aligned (like without any highlighting).

I tried the `Verbatim` and `lstlisting` environments like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\%]
```

or

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
```

in combination with a then escaped `colorbox` command - the highlighting works - but the additional spaces are introduced and screw up the character alignment.

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the `alltt` environment from the package with the same name is better suited here. It makes everything verbatim except `\`,`{` and `}`, similar to
`\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]`.

The mentioned added space is due to the used `\fboxsep` which makes the box bigger. You can avoid this by setting this value to zero, either globally or locally using a own macro. This however makes the box very tight on all four sites. An added `\strut` makes sure that it has always the same height and depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{alltt}
% Global:
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
% Better:
\newcommand\hi[2][red]{{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \colorbox{#1}{#2\strut}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
hello \colorbox{red}{world\strut} blah
hello world blub
hello \hi{world} blub
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Another alternative, the best one IHMO, is to compensate for the `fboxsep` before and after the box:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{alltt}
% Compensate for fbox sep:
\newcommand\Hi[2][red]{%
  \hspace*{-\fboxsep}%
  \colorbox{#1}{#2}%
  \hspace*{-\fboxsep}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
hello world blah
hello \Hi{world} blah
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

Just set `\fboxsep=0pt` to reduce the extra space around `\colorbox`.

And here's another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\colorlet{mycolor}{red!50}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,
  escapechar=`}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo`\hl{bar}`foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]